# google api return kilometers instead of miles

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I have an application to calculate distance between two points.

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=%22)
+ origins + "&destinations=" + destinations + "&units=imperial...

I am setting the units to imperial , however some distances are returned in Kms and Ft. Do I need to set any other parameter?

Comment: Can you provide sample origins/destinations that demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Do you mean Kms and meters ? It's impossible for it to be Kms and feet. For example `{"distance"=>{"text"=>"0.2 km", "value"=>174}`, here text is in kms, and value is in meters.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code I used to get the distance in miles.

**Method 1:**
You will have to call the google map api JS library with your key then use this below code.

```
var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.930385, -3.118425);
var origin2 = 'Greenwich, England';
var destinationA = 'Stockholm, Sweden';
var destinationB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.087692, 14.421150);
//var  uniteSystem = 'IMPERIAL';
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix(
  {
    origins: [origin1],
    destinations: [destinationA],
    travelMode: 'DRIVING' ,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL   
  }
  , callback);

function callback(response, status) {
  // See Parsing the Results for
  // the basics of a callback function.
  console.log(response);
}
```

You will have an array of element as response.

**Method 2:**
This is the url method I used to get the distance in miles.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&destinations=41.43206,-81.38992&key=TOUR_API_KEY

Remember to change the API key.

Answer (score 2):

Use **unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC** if you want result in **Kilometers**.
Use **unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL** if you want result in **Miles**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var distanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
     distanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: ["10 West 35th Street, Chicago, IL, USA"], //$("#autocompleteDeparture").val()
        destinations: ["Union Station, South Canal Street, Chicago, IL, USA"], //$("#autocompleteArrival").val()
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL, //use "IMPERIAL" for Miles, "METRIC" for KMs
        durationInTraffic: true,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    },
    function (response, status) {
        if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            console.log('Error:', status);
        } else {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The distance.text field is expressed in the units passed in the request; the distance.value field is always expressed in meters.

Refer to [the Distance Matrix developer guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#unit_systems) and you'll find this blurb:

> Note: this unit system setting only affects the text displayed within distance fields. The distance fields also contain values which are always expressed in meters.

Comment: Thank you Mike Post for your response. What is weird is that I always get the text field (See code below) , this is a batch process , it gave me around 10,000 distances and most of them are in miles but have some in Kms

Comment: HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
 
                    Rootobject _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(result);
                    Console.WriteLine(_result.status);
                    if (_result.status == "OK")
                    {
                        return _result.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text.ToString();
                    }

Answer (score 0):

just change unit from imperial to km,

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" + origins + "&destinations=" + destinations + "&units=km...
```